# Is there anyway to include plural word when searching on SQL database?

Tags: php, sql, regex, database, .htaccess

Is there anyway to include plural keyword when searching on SQL database?

Almost all of my product database as single keyword only.

Such as searching with blue area rug <-- This would be display the results.

But if searching with blue area rugs <-- This will not display any results.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Once you've solved the particular issue of plurals, you'll find something else you will want to compensate for, like switched word order and such. So go and research natural language search engines right now before you go deeper down the rabbit hole.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: why did you include a snapshot of code rather than real code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this can solve your problem or not.A function 'SOUNDEX' it may help you.

```
select * from tbl where title like '%rug%' or  SOUNDEX(title) = SOUNDEX('rugs')
```